# Entity Framework Connection Resiliency

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

According to Microsoft at this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-resiliency#execution-strategies-and-transactions), this is an example of using an execution strategy with transactions...

```
using var db = new BloggingContext();
var strategy = db.Database.CreateExecutionStrategy();

strategy.Execute(
    () =>
    {
        using var context = new BloggingContext();
        using var transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction();

        context.Blogs.Add(new Blog { Url = "http://blogs.msdn.com/dotnet" });
        context.SaveChanges();

        context.Blogs.Add(new Blog { Url = "http://blogs.msdn.com/visualstudio" });
        context.SaveChanges();

        transaction.Commit();
    });
```

Notice that there are two database context instances being created in the sample. And elsewhere, I've read that you are, indeed, supposed to instantiate a context within your execution strategy delegate.

Question: **What is the relationship between the context from which the ExecutionStrategy was created, and the context within the delegate?**